# Creating a completion table (PHP and MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My database has a challenges table where there are these columns: `Challenge_Name, Challenge_Description`. I have a 2nd table called `completed_challenges_junction` and it has these columns: `Member_Name, Challenge_Name`.
I need a way to display all of the challenge names from the challenges table along with the member names within the `completed_challenges_junction`. If there is no match then I would like it to display `NULL`.
I think I'm pretty close to having my SQL code working, here is what I have now.

```sql
SELECT challenges.Challenge_Name, challenges.Challenge_Description, completed_challenges_junction.Member_Names 
FROM challenges 
LEFT JOIN completed_challenges_junction ON challenges.Challenge_Name=completed_challenges_junction.Challenge_Name
```

This works but also bring duplicate entries of another member. If i use `WHERE Member_Name='testmember'` it only brings the entries of the member when I need it to still display all `Challenge_Name`s.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say it 'bring(s) duplicate entries of another member'.  You mention that you want to display all challenges (and I am assuming all instances of challenges taken)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    A.Challenge_Name,A.Challenge_Description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(B.Member_Names,'')) Member_Names
FROM
    challenges A
    LEFT JOIN completed_challenges_junction B ON
    A.Challenge_Name=B.Challenge_Name AND
    A.Challenge_Description=B.Challenge_Description
GROUP BY
    A.Challenge_Name,A.Challenge_Description
;
```

or

```
SELECT
    A.Challenge_Name,A.Challenge_Description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(B.Member_Names,'')) Member_Names
FROM
    challenges A
    LEFT JOIN completed_challenges_junction B
    USING (Challenge_Name,Challenge_Description)
GROUP BY
    A.Challenge_Name,A.Challenge_Description
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` condition like this

```
SELECT challenges.Challenge_Name, challenges.Challenge_Description, completed_challenges_junction.Member_Names 
FROM challenges 
LEFT JOIN completed_challenges_junction ON (
  challenges.Challenge_Name=completed_challenges_junction.Challenge_Name
  AND Member_Name='testmember'
)
```

This way only *testmember* entries will come up from completed_challanges_junction, but all challenges will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but maybe you are looking for 'group by' clause and group_concat function:

```sql
SELECT challenges.Challenge_Name, challenges.Challenge_Description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(completed_challenges_junction.Member_Names SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM challenges 
LEFT JOIN completed_challenges_junction
    ON challenges.Challenge_Name=completed_challenges_junction.Challenge_Name
GROUP BY challenges.Challenge_Name
```

This query will return result where each Challenge_Name occurs only once.